# Unable to edit ribbon to display custom tabs on Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013

[image: Image of the customize ribbon currently enabled]

I have been trying to customize the ribbon with more options like smart tool tabs, chart tool tabs, add-ins, blog post etc. But the only tabs that appear on the ribbon are view and developer. Anything after that won't appear on the ribbon at all. Any help would be appreciated as I have tried everything possible. The version of Office I am using is Office Standard 2013. I have already tried the options in a similar question, but the problem is that it doesn't create a grouping which I expect would be created if I use Customize the Ribbon option.

Comment: Did your tabs *ever* show up correctly?  I ask because your screenshot is missing many of the default ribbon tabs.

Comment: I have disabled them in this case. They work fine but its the ones after developer that never show up on the ribbon

Comment: The solution in the duplicate question does not work in this case